# Download WorldPop data (100m) in R

Tags: raster, r, export, population

I am trying to download population count data (100m pixel size) from WorldPop using the `R` package `wpgpDownloadR`. The code:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("wpgp/wpgpDownloadR")
library(wpgpDownloadR)

wd = "path"

r <- wpgpGetCountryDataset(ISO3 = "GRC",
                            covariate = "ppp_2018"
                            destDir = path)
```

But i am getting this error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                            covariate = "ppp_2018"
                            destDir"
```

Even if I change the `destDir` argument to `destDir = "the/whole/path"` I am getting the same error. Also, I tried the `method` argument without success. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993587/13087048) solution, but still the same error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of path is not correct, and you miss a comma after "ppp_2018". The following works, creating a "path" directory inside the current working directory and downloading the file:

```
#devtools::install_github("wpgp/wpgpDownloadR")
library(wpgpDownloadR)

path <- paste0(getwd(),"/path")
dir.create(path)

r <- wpgpGetCountryDataset(ISO3 = "GRC",
                           covariate = "ppp_2018",
                           destDir = path)
```